# Один RestController на все EndPoint vs сколько EndPoint столько и RestController

Tags: java, spring

Вот сейчас у меня все EndPoint обрабатываются в одном RestController'е, который содержит порядка пяти заAutowire'ных сервисов.  Это что получается что на каждый запрос будет создаваться новый контроллер и к нему будут подгружаться сервисы, которые для данного запроса вообще не нужны?

В общем это показалось мне не очень рациональным. Есть ли какая то BestPractice по данному вопросу?

Comment: А почему Вы решили, что для каждого запроса создается новый контроллер? И, к слову, установка ссылок на сервисы очень простая операция (если конечно сервисы - синглетоны).

Comment: @VladimirParfenov ну да, это наверно я не так выразился, там скорее всего пул объектов  контроллера. Если по умолчанию сервис - синглтон, тогда у меня они являются синглтонами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Spring, все контроллеры являются синглетонами, которые, также, сделаны и потокобезопасными. Как именно конкретно, я не могу ответить, потому что в такие  дебри той технологии не погружался.
Так что, для каждого запроса не будет создаваться нового экземпляра контроллера. Да это и нелогично с точки зрения производительности. Можете смело оставлять вашу текущую логику и не бояться потерять в производительности.